# Not able to extract information from a X509 Certificate into a temporary file using openssl library targeted for windows

Tags: c, visual-c++, openssl, x509

```
if (!(fp = fopen(TEMP_STORE_CERTIFICATE, "w"))) {

    free(TEMP_STORE_CERTIFICATE);
    return 0;

  }

PEM_write_X509(fp, x);
fclose(fp);
```

I am writing this C code in Visual Studio 2010 Windows. When execution gets at `PEM_write_X509;` the stream/console is blocked and the code does not proceed. Basically, the function extracts the information from the certificate and puts it into a temporary file. But the execution does not proceeds. The function is from the Open SSL library.

Comment: Why is there a `free()` there? This is c++, use `new` and `delete`. Also, where is `x` defined, is it a valid `X509*`?

Comment: It is a C code. Sorry for wrong tagging, and yes the declarations are correct. x has been defined as X509 *

Comment: So if you breakpoint at `fclose(fp)`, the breakpoint never gets hit?

Comment: Yes.. and i am not able to know whether it is related to anyhow openssl initialization and i have wasted 3 hours already on it :(

Comment: I guess, PEM_write_X509 enters into an infinite loop.

Comment: hmm.. Is it open source? Can you step into the function?

Comment: Please try with BIO methods.